# resignFirstResponder not hiding keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, uitextfield

I have three textfield.

```
vacDate
vacTime
vacType
```

When I click `vacDate` or `vacTime`, I show datepicker `myDatePicker`.

Also when I click anywhere I call hideAllKeyboards which hides all keyboards and datepicker.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing===%@" , textField.text);
    CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    myDatePicker.hidden = YES;
    if (textField==vacDate || textField==vacTime) {
        [vacDate resignFirstResponder];
        [vacTime resignFirstResponder];
        [vacType resignFirstResponder];
        myDatePicker.hidden = NO;
    }


    if (textField==vacType) {
        translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -60);
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    self.view.transform = translation;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(IBAction)hideAllKeyboards {
    NSLog(@"hideAllKeyboards...");
    [vacDate resignFirstResponder];
    [vacTime resignFirstResponder];
    [vacType resignFirstResponder];
    myDatePicker.hidden = YES;

    NSLog(@"my date data is %@", myDatePicker.date);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[myDatePicker date]];
    NSLog(@"my date is ::: %@", strDate);
    vacDate.text = strDate;

    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh mm a"];
    strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[myDatePicker date]];
    NSLog(@"my date is ==%@==", strDate);
    strDate = [strDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@":"];
    strDate = [strDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":A" withString:@" A"];
    strDate = [strDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":P" withString:@" P"];
    vacTime.text = strDate;


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Below is what I am doing.

Tap on vacDate and then set time. Once time is set, tap anywhere. Date and time gets set in vacDate and vacTime. Now I go to vacType and type text and then click Done. Now all keyboards are getting hided.

Now again I click on vacType. Now I see the keyboard (default). Now I click vacDate or vacTime. **Here I was expecting to display datepicker as happened at first step, but I see default keyboard**.

Any idea why resignFirstResponder is not working on all keyboards. As keyboards don't call resignFirstResponder, I am not able to see datepicker.

---

### Edit 1

With the code I have, I noticed that when I type in vacType and then click back to vacDate or vacTime, I see upper part of datepicker, but the default keyboard is not hided. I still see the default keyboard. I want to hide this keyboard forcefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what about using `endEditing` to hide your keyboard instead of `resignFirstResponder`:-

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

**EDIT**

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { {
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing===%@" , textField.text);
    CGAffineTransform translation = CGAffineTransformIdentity;


    if (textField==vacDate || textField==vacTime) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        self.view.transform = translation;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        myDatePicker.hidden = NO;
        return NO;
    }
    else
    { 

         if (textField==vacType) {
           translation = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -60);
         }
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    self.view.transform = translation;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    myDatePicker.hidden = YES;
     return YES;
    }

}
```

NOTE:-

instead of checking `Textfiled` like  ***if (textField==vacType)*** use Tag while use UITextfiled in UI or programatically. This is the better option for checking which `text filed` you are editing. like ***if(textfiled.tag==1)***

**[DEMO link](http://ge.tt/7xjPk2n/v/0)**

Comment: as par your code in this method: **hideAllKeyboards** myDatePicker.hidden = YES; remove this do one thing create seprate one method for only displying datapicker so after code of [self.view endEditing:YES]; then call this methid like [self openDatePicker];

Comment: if I don't have `myDatePicker.hidden = YES;`, then how I will hide myDatePicker?

Comment: i thought you want to appear datepicker at hideAllkeyboards method and i seen this hidden code for datePicker ther that's why i saying do that think for creat seprate method for appearing DatePicker

Comment: if I click on any first two cell, I will see datepicker... else it will hide datepicker.. everything is working.. but facing problem when I am going from third to first or second textfield..

Comment: check my edited answer use **textFieldShouldBeginEditing** delegate as par my example this should help you may be this not parfect as par your need but it just example.

Comment: regarding tag, I think it will have same effect... its just I will have tag... textfield will also have same effect...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34303/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-fahim-parkar)

Answer (score 1):

What I did is did not show default keyboard when vacDate and vacTime is clicked.

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    if (textField==vacType) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    } else {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        myDatePicker.hidden = NO;
        return NO;
    }
}
```

This solved my problem...